# wifi adapter disabled

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Lenovo idea pad with windows 10, I have dual booted the laptop with ubuntu 18.04, I am unable to connect to wifi"wifi adapter not found", To rectify the issue I need to install the drivers through a wired connection, but my laptop does not have an ethernet port . Is there any other way to solve the issue. Kindly help me.

Answer (score -1):

Locate the drivers on your phone or via another device and upload it via USB cable or USB flash drive.

[Solved](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/No-WiFi-adapter-in-ubuntu-18-04-LTS/td-p/6785623)

Also, search on here before asking. This has been asked many times and I have found many solutions on here.